# Read-only and non-computed variable properties in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, properties

I'm trying to figure out something with the new Apple Swift language. Let's say I used to do something like the following in Objective-C. I have `readonly` properties, and they cannot be individually changed. However, using a specific method, the properties are changed in a logical way.

I take the following example, a very simple clock. I would write this in Objective-C.

```
@interface Clock : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSUInteger hours;
@property (readonly) NSUInteger minutes;
@property (readonly) NSUInteger seconds;

- (void)incrementSeconds;

@end

@implementation Clock

- (void)incrementSeconds {
     _seconds++;

     if (_seconds == 60) {
        _seconds = 0;
        _minutes++;

         if (_minutes == 60) {
            _minutes = 0;
            _hours++;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

For a specific purpose, we cannot touch the seconds, minutes and hours directly, and it's only allowed to increment second by second using a method. Only this method could change the values by using the trick of the instance variables.

Since there are no such things in Swift, I'm trying to find an equivalent. If I do this:

```
class Clock : NSObject {

    var hours:   UInt = 0
    var minutes: UInt = 0
    var seconds: UInt = 0

    func incrementSeconds() {

        self.seconds++

        if self.seconds == 60 {

            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes++

            if self.minutes == 60 {

                self.minutes = 0
                self.hours++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That would work, but anybody could change directly the properties.

Maybe I already had a bad design in Objective-C and that's why the potential new Swift equivalent is not making sense. If not and if someone have an answer, I would be very grateful ;)

Maybe the future **Access Control Mechanisms** promised by Apple is the answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Access control is the answer. You would create readonly computed properties, while use private properties for the actual data.

Comment: Make sure to open a bug report (enhancement) to let Apple know how direly this is missing.

Comment: For new users: Scroll to the bottom...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift readonly external, readwrite internal property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708439/swift-readonly-external-readwrite-internal-property)

Answer (score 369):

Simply prefix the property declaration with `private(set)`, like so:

```
public private(set) var hours:   UInt = 0
public private(set) var minutes: UInt = 0
public private(set) var seconds: UInt = 0
```

`private` keeps it local to a source file, while `internal` keeps it local to the module/project.

`private(set)` creates a `read-only` property, while `private` sets both, `set` and `get` to private.

Comment: "private" to keep it local to a source file, "internal" to keep it local to the module/project.

private(set) only makes the set private. Private makes both set and get functions private

Comment: The first comment should be added to this answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Right now (Swift 3.0.1) Access Control Levels changed: "fileprivate" declaration can be accessed only by code in the same source file as the declaration”. "private" declaration can be accessed only by code within the declaration’s immediate enclosing scope.

Answer (score 20):

There are two basic ways of doing what you want. First way is by having a private property and and a public computed property which returns that property:

```
public class Clock {

  private var _hours = 0

  public var hours: UInt {
    return _hours
  }

}
```

But this can be achieved in a different, shorter way, as stated in the section ["Access Control"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3) of the ["The Swift Programming Language"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book:

```
public class Clock {

    public private(set) var hours = 0

}
```

As a side note, you MUST provide a public initialiser when declaring a public type. Even if you provide default values to all properties, `init()` must be defined explicitly public:

```
public class Clock {

    public private(set) var hours = 0

    public init() {
      hours = 0
    }
    // or simply `public init() {}`

}
```

This is also explained in the same section of the book, when talking about default initialisers.

Answer (score 5):

Since there are no access controls (meaning that you can't make an access contract that differs depending on who the caller is), here's what I would do for now:

```
class Clock {
    struct Counter {
        var hours = 0;
        var minutes = 0;
        var seconds = 0;
        mutating func inc () {
            if ++seconds >= 60 {
                seconds = 0
                if ++minutes >= 60 {
                    minutes = 0
                    ++hours
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var counter = Counter()
    var hours : Int { return counter.hours }
    var minutes : Int { return counter.minutes }
    var seconds : Int { return counter.seconds }
    func incrementTime () { self.counter.inc() }
}
```

This merely adds a level of indirection, as it were, to direct access to the counter; another class *can* make a Clock and then access its counter directly. But the *idea* — i.e., the contract we're trying to make — is that another class should use the Clock's top-level properties and methods only. We can't *enforce* that contract, but actually it was pretty much impossible to enforce in Objective-C too.

Comment: Looks like this has changed since then, correct?

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5

Comment: @Yar sure, this whole question / answer was written _long_ before access control was added to Swift. And Swift is _still_ evolving, so answers will continue to be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Actually access control (which does not exist yet in Swift) is not as enforced as you may think in Objective C. People **can** modify your readonly variables directly, if they really want to. They just do not do it with the public interface of the class.

You can do something similar in Swift (cut&paste of your code, plus some modifications, I did not test it):

```
class Clock : NSObject {

    var _hours:   UInt = 0
    var _minutes: UInt = 0
    var _seconds: UInt = 0

    var hours: UInt {
    get {
      return _hours
    }
    }

    var minutes: UInt {
    get {
      return _minutes
    }
    }

    var seconds: UInt  {
    get {
      return _seconds
    }
    }

    func incrementSeconds() {

        self._seconds++

        if self._seconds == 60 {

            self._seconds = 0
            self._minutes++

            if self._minutes == 60 {

                self._minutes = 0
                self._hours++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is the same as what you have in Objective C except that the actual stored properties are visible in the public interface.

In swift you can also do something more interesting, which you can also do in Objective C, but it's probably prettier in swift (edited in the browser, I did not test it):

```
class Clock : NSObject {

    var hours: UInt = 0

    var minutes: UInt {
    didSet {
      hours += minutes / 60
      minutes %= 60
    }
    }

    var seconds: UInt  {
    didSet {
      minutes += seconds / 60
      seconds %= 60
    }
    }

    // you do not really need this any more
    func incrementSeconds() {
        seconds++
    }
}
```

Comment: "People can modify your readonly variables directly" - what do you mean exactly? How?

Comment: I was referring to Objective C. In Objective C you have dynamic access to everything about a class through the Objective C Runtime APIs.

Comment: i somehow understood you implied that for swift. Got curious. Thanks