# Swift readonly external, readwrite internal property

Tags: objective-c, properties, swift

In Swift, what is the conventional way to define the common pattern where a property is to be externally readonly, but modifiable internally by the class (and subclasses) that own it.

In Objective-C, there are the following options:

- Declare the property as readonly in the interface and use a class extension to access the property internally. This is message-based access, hence it works nicely with KVO, atomicity, etc.
- Declare the property as readonly in the interface, but access the backing ivar internally. As the default access for an ivar is protected, this works nicely in a class hierarchy, where subclasses will also be able to modify the value, but the field is otherwise readonly.

In Java the convention is:

- Declare a protected field, and implement a public, read-only getter (method).

What is the idiom for Swift?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Given a class property, you can specify a different access level by prefixing the property declaration with the access modifier followed by `get` or `set` between parenthesis. For example, a class property with a public getter and a private setter will be declared as:

```
private(set) public var readonlyProperty: Int
```

Suggested reading: [Getters and Setters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID18)

Martin's considerations about accessibility level are still valid - i.e. there's no `protected` modifier, `internal` restricts access to the module only, `private` to the current file only, and `public` with no restrictions.

## Swift 3 notes

2 new access modifiers, `fileprivate` and `open` have been added to the language, while `private` and `public` have been slightly modified:

- `open` applies to class and class members only: it's used to allow a class to be subclassed or a member to be overridden outside of the module where they are defined. `public` instead makes the class or the member publicly accessible, but not inheritable or overridable
- `private` now makes a member visible and accessible from the enclosing declaration only, whereas `fileprivate` to the entire file where it is contained

More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3).

Comment: Nice! (I have take the liberty to add the missing `var` keyword to make it compile.)

Comment: oh thanks a lot :) I usually copy from playground and paste, but this time I have probably done it wrong.

Comment: Note as of Jan-2015 this syntax is not quite right if the outer class is not `public` - it should be `internal` or nothing at all (which defaults to whatever the class is - `public` or `internal`) - i.e. `private(set) var readonlyProperty: Int`

Comment: Well the syntax is correct taking into account that right before the code I wrote _a class property with a **public** getter and a **private** setter_ - it is just an example. But yes, access modifiers for properties must be "compatible" with the class/struct access modifier.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, I guess this has changed since the answer was written, but `private` now restricts to the current *declaration* (not file) and `fileprivate` is available for restricting to the current file. Also `public` does have some restrictions and `open` is needed for no restrictions. [Details here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3).

Comment: Hi I am also stuck in some access level issues. Please check once: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56769304/1364053

Answer (score 4):

As per @Antonio, we can use a single property to access as the `readOnly` property value publicly and `readWrite` privately. Below is  my illustration:

```
class MyClass {

    private(set) public var publicReadOnly: Int = 10

    //as below, we can modify the value within same class which is private access
    func increment() {
        publicReadOnly += 1
    }

    func decrement() {
        publicReadOnly -= 1
    }
}

let object = MyClass()
print("Initial  valule: \(object.publicReadOnly)")

//For below line we get the compile error saying : "Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'publicReadOnly' setter is inaccessible"
//object.publicReadOnly += 1

object.increment()
print("After increment method call: \(object.publicReadOnly)")

object.decrement()
print("After decrement method call: \(object.publicReadOnly)")
```

And here is the output:

```
  Initial  valule: 10
  After increment method call: 11
  After decrement method call: 10
```