# Does Swift support read-only stored properties in Class Type

Tags: swift

In Swift supported read-only computed properties.
Does Swift support read-only stored properties in Class type?
If It does not, Can I have a chance to implement code like read-only property.

In objective-c looks like

```
interface file:
@property (readonly) NSInteger number

implementation file:
- (void)method {

    // can still access _number property
    _number = 100;
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: read documentation, it will tell you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift readonly external, readwrite internal property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708439/swift-readonly-external-readwrite-internal-property)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
    private var _x: Int = 0

    var x: Int {
        get {
            return _x
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi zisoft, thanks for that. so, I have to use stored property + computed property + access control, right?

Comment: Hi zisoft, finally, I found that I can use "public private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0" to solve my question. Thanks for your reply.