# Private property in data modeling and initializing

Tags: swift

I'm beginner in Swift development.

I saw a video about data modeling in Swift. This code below:

```
private var _name: String!

var name: String {
    return _name
}
```

Why we need to do that? I know it's good but can you explain to me about how it's better than normal ways like just define directly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25720651/1187415 for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your case you will have Invalid redeclaration of name - variable.

```
 private var _name: String!
 name = "xyz" {
 return _name
 }
```

or

```
 private var _name: String = ""
name {return _name}
```