# Read-only access for instance property in Swift

Tags: swift, properties, readonly, access-control

I am aware of `private(set)` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708439/swift-readonly-external-readwrite-internal-property) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081194/read-only-and-non-computed-variable-properties-in-swift) but it doesn't seem to work for my situation where I have instance variable with internal properties.

I have an instance property where I would like it to have read-only access. The following code shows some concrete example.

```
class Point {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

class Sprite {
    private(set) var origin = Point(0,0)

    func incrementX() {
        origin.x += 1
    }

    func incrementY() {
        origin.y += 1
    }
}
```

Here, my intent is to make `Sprite` the sole owner of `origin`, allowing it to be the only one who can modify it, otherwise making `origin` read-only to the public. However:

```
var sprite = Sprite()
sprite.origin = Point(100, 200)        // Error: setter is inaccessibie. Expected behavior.
sprite.origin.x = 150                  // No error. The origin.x will be set to 150.
```

Apparently I can still modify `origin` by modifying internal `x` and `y` directly, but this is not my intent.

How do I make `origin` truly read-only? Am I missing something?

Modifying `Point` to `private var x: Int` or `fileprivate var x: Int` won't work for me because I want to be able to let an external class like `Sprite` modify `Point`.

*Edit*: From comment below, this is not my actual scenario, since someone comments that I should be using `CGPoint`. The code serves as as example to make my question more concrete. I actually have a complex class as instance property in another class, not this simple `Point`. I also can't use it as `struct` due to other design constraints.

*Edit2*: An answer below points out that you cannot prevent the reference from being mutable. That's a limitation in Swift I just learned, because apparently, I can achieve exactly what I wanted in C++ using `Point const &`:

```
class Point {
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    Point & operator=(const Point & rhs) {
        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }

    ...

};

class Sprite {

    Point origin;

public:

    Sprite()
    : origin(0,0)
    {}

    // HERE
    Point const & getOrigin() const { return origin; }

    void incrementX() {    origin.x += 1; }
    void incrementY() {    origin.y += 1; }

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Sprite sprite = Sprite();
    Point const & o = sprite.getOrigin();

    cout << "o: " << o << endl;  // (0,0)
//    o.x = 10;                  // Error: Cannot assign to const-qualified type.
//    o = Point (100, 200);      // Error: no viable overlaod =.


    sprite.incrementX();

    cout << "o: " << o << endl;  // (1,0). Swift can't get this behavior with `struct Point`, but it won't prevent some writing attempts with `class Point`.
    cout << "sprite.origin: " << sprite.getOrigin() << endl;  // (1,0).

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not a "class property". It is an _instance_ property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `origin` completely `private`. The only public thing should be a *read-only computed property*. Your public `incrementX` and `incrementY` methods will still work as desired, because they are allowed to access `origin`.

If Point is a struct, then it is sufficient for this read-only property to return `origin`, because it will be a copy:

```
var currentOrigin : Point {
    return self.origin
}
```

But if you insist on making Point a class rather than a struct, then you are vending a *reference* to the same Point instance you are already retaining, and you *cannot prevent it from being mutable*. Therefore you will have to *produce* a copy of `self.origin` *yourself*, so that you are not vending a mutable reference to your own private instance:

```
var currentOrigin : Point {
    return Point(self.origin.x,self.origin.y)
}
```

(The way Objective-C Cocoa typically solves this sort of problem is by implementing a *class cluster* of immutable/mutable pairs; for example, we maintain an NSMutableString but we vend an NSString copy, so that our mutable string cannot be mutated behind our back. However, I think you are being very foolish to reject the use a struct, since this is one of Swift's huge advantages over Objective-C, i.e. it solves *the very problem you are having*.)

Comment: I decided to accept your answer since it's closest to what I am looking for. Maybe a language feature where one can keep *reference* to an instance without being able to modify it doesn't yet exist in Swift, as far as I'm aware of. But for now, even though `struct` doesn't keep the copy updated by design, it still won't tax the performance since Swift has under-the-hood optimization to copy only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I also disagree with being "foolish" when I have a legit use case for insisting on `class` instead of `struct`. Once I get a copy from `struct` instance, I naturally lose all the updates made to the original copy. My point (no pun intended) is that I want to be able to keep references to the same instance while making only certain owner of that reference capable of *both* read and write. See a C++ example in my updated OP.

Comment: The ability of C++ to pass a pointer (to save time/resources) while preventing the recipient from mutating the thing pointed to, is certainly cool. To be sure, Swift has nothing parallel. But, as I've said, Point can be a struct and yet `incrementX` and `incrementY` still work exactly as written. And there are ways of passing around a struct's address so that the recipient _can_ implicitly write back to the original (e.g. `inout`). The real trouble here, it seems to me, is that the question you asked isn't the question you want answered; your example is an unrepresentative reduction.

Answer (score 4):

Just make `Point` a struct

```
struct Point {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

class Sprite {
    private(set) var origin = Point(0,0)

    func incrementX() {
        origin.x += 1
    }

    func incrementY() {
        origin.y += 1
    }
}
```

And try again

```
var sprite = Sprite()
sprite.origin.x = 1
error: cannot assign to property: 'origin' setter is inaccessible
```

> BTW: Why don't you simply use `CGPoint` instead of defining a new type?

Comment: @appzYorLife Thanks for the reply. My code serves as as example to make my question more concrete. I actually have a complex class as property in another class, not this simple `Point`. I also can't use it as struct due to other design constraints. However, do you know why Swift handles `struct` and `class` differently in this regard?

Comment: @HuaTham: That's because structs are value types. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Point {
 private var x: Int
 private var y: Int

 init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
     self.x = x
     self.y = y
 }

 func incrementX() {
     x += 1
 }

 func incrementY() {
     y += 1
 }

 func setX(_ value : Int){
     x = value
 }

 func setY(_ value : Int){
     y = value
 }
}

class Sprite {

    private (set) var origin = Point(0,0)

}
```

if you need to get the `x` and `y` value you should add getter in your `Point` class like this:

```
func getX()->Int{
    return x
}
```

so you can try this:

```
let sprite = Sprite()
sprite.origin.incrementX()

let point = Point(10,20)
point.setX(12)
point.setY(100)
```

so you can have `origin` read-only, in my opinion you have to set `x` and `y` private.

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP's problem. This only moved direct access to x and y to setters, which still allows the underlying Point to be modified in the way the OP didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get your desired result by exposing Point directly, it is a class and will be passed by reference. You can use a protocol to only expose the parts of Point you desire.

```
protocol ReadablePoint {
    var x: Int { get }
    var y: Int { get }
}

class Point: ReadablePoint {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

class Sprite {
    private var _origin = Point(0,0)
    var origin: ReadablePoint { return _origin }

    func incrementX() {
        _origin.x += 1
    }

    func incrementY() {
        _origin.y += 1
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
var sprite = Sprite()
sprite.origin = Point(100, 200)        // error: cannot assign to property: 'origin' is a get-only property
sprite.origin.x = 150                  // error: cannot assign to property: 'x' is a get-only property
```

Comment: I think "PointProtocol" is supposed to be "ReadablePoint".

Comment: This might be just outside the context of this question, but:
(sprite.origin as! Point).x = 5

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
class Point {
var x: Int
var y: Int

init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
}
}

class Sprite {
private var privatePoint = Point(0,0)
var origin:Point{
    get{
        return privatePoint
    }
}
}
```

so you can do this :

```
var sprite = Sprite()
sprite.origin = Point(100, 200)        // Error: setter is inaccessibie. Expected behavior.
sprite.origin.x = 150                  // No error. The origin.x will be set to 150.
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading this incorrectly, this doesn't seem to solve the OP's problem, it has the same issues the OP sought to avoid,